# Should I implement my own JCA adapter to access file system? Or use an existing one?

Tags: ejb, weblogic, adapter, jca

I am doing Java EE development on Weblogic, one of my EJB needs to process data from files.  Since it is not recommended to access file system directly from EJB, I think a JCA adapter will be needed.

There are some examples for creating JCA adapter, but I wonder if I need to implement it by myself. If there are some well-implemented JCA adapters, I think I could make use of it by doing some configurations?

Oracle® Fusion Middleware seems to offer some JCA adapters, which is called "Technology Adapters".  Can I use them with just some configurations? Or I have to develop my own adapter following JCA specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel.  The existing file system adapters from Oracle should do what you need.

You still need to interface to it as a JCA client however.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I know the correct direction.  Configuring the adapter seems not easy though, the user guide of the adapter is almost one thousand pages...